# Need a method for determining variable groupings in R

Tags: r, categorical-data, predictive-models, p-value, multiple-comparisons

I am using R and trying to group one of my variables into larger groups so they have credibility.  I have been manually setting each factor of the variable as the reference level, looking at all other factors p values relative to the reference, and then repeating for every factor. With this info you can easily see which groups are and are not significantly different from each other.

Is there an automated way to do get the p values for each reference level? It would be incredibly useful.

Comment: What you are describing is invalid. No R function will overcome that fact. We can discuss this process & a strategy that might be valid instead, however. (Note that asking for R code is off-topic here anyway.) But why do you feel the need to collapse insignificant groups in the first place? Why would they "have [more] credibility"? What would that even mean?

Comment: If I don't collapse the insignificant groups I will be overfitting the model. I am trying to get as much lift out of the variable as I can without overfitting.

Comment: Actually, I think it is much more likely that you will overfit the model if you do collapse the insignificant groups. How much data do you have & how many total variables are there (continuous variables + groups)?

Comment: @gung is correct.  This strategy would make things worse, and will cause you to report results in a misleading way.  You need to be straightforward about how many parameters you give the _opportunity_ to be in the model.

Comment: So if not every level of the variable is significant, then I have to exclude the variable from the model? That seems like wasting valuable information. If I know two levels of the variable are not significantly different from each other I can't allow them to receive a different coefficient in my model. I am suggesting that I group similar levels of the variable together.

Comment: No, you retain the variable (the entire variable) whether all levels differ from each other or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I believe a GLMM is the appropriate solution to handling levels of a variable that are insignificant, as this essentially credibility weights the coefficient for each level of the variable. This paper provides a good description (See 9.1):

http://www.casact.org/pubs/monographs/papers/05-Goldburd-Khare-Tevet.pdf